# Excel Web Query TIME allways as DATETIME

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a problem with `MS Excel` and `web query`. When I try to get a date from web query, Excel always converts it to datetime.

Example:

`00:03:20` convert to `28.04.2015 00:03:20`. I know, I can hide date with column format, but I need have time values for other calculations like:

```
Time1 = IsBetween(TimeAVG+(TimeAVG*20%);TimeAVG-(TimeAVG*20%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acquire pure time from datetime, subtract the date portion in the sheet.

```
Time = Datetime - INT(Datetime)
```